# Laravel storing images

Tags: laravel, web, laravel-5.6

I'm building my app with laravel 5.6
The question is simple and general, not only for laravel.

How should I store images in database?

Should I store a hash from the image? a particular name?

ty!

Comment: You can store image filename in database. And store all the images in specific folder on server. After that you might access your images via filename stored in database. Take a look on [file system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

You should store image name and image name hash on db then store file on local folder, cloud, s3 and etc.

For access this image, you should use link with hashed name and when you are showing this image, you should set response header with real image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the database to **store the path or the URL** to that image, **never** the hash or anything in that way.

For laravel specifically you can use the built-in [Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem) and a great library to deal with storing and doing all kinds of things with images is [Image Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/).

So you'll get your user image, save it in the storage (or the public folder, if the image is public) and then get the path you saved so you can save it in the database.

Comment: I will try it out! thank you1